# PackageNotFound error while executing .exe file made by PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am trying to make an .exe file of a python script which checks sentence similarity. The script uses the following libraries:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
```

However, when I run the file created by PyInstaller, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 105, in require_version
 File "importlib\metadata.py", line 472, in version
 File "importlib\metadata.py", line 445, in distribution
 File "importlib\metadata.py", line 169, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: tqdm

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: The 'tqdm>=4.27' distribution was not found and is required by this application. 
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main
```

I already have "tqdm" installed and also tried pip install transformers -U, I am not sure what is causing this problem. Is there someone who can help me out on this?

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by using the following command on cmd when running PyInstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=pytorch --collect-data torch --copy-metadata torch --copy-metadata tqdm --copy-metadata regex --copy-metadata sacremoses --copy-metadata requests --copy-metadata packaging --copy-metadata filelock --copy-metadata numpy --copy-metadata tokenizers --copy-metadata importlib_metadata --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._cython_blas" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree._utils" BERT.py
```

Furthermore, I installed two more packages:

> pip install importlib_metadata
> pip install wheel

Answer (score 1):

Using '--recursive-copy-metadata' will save your tons of time.

For example:

```
pyinstaller --recursive-copy-metadata diffusers YOURFILE.py
```

Documentation:

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=copy-metadata#cmdoption-recursive-copy-metadata

Comment: if you are wondering how to do this in a spec file 

```python
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = []
datas += copy_metadata('transformers', recursive=True)
```