# 'tqdm>=4.27' distribution was not found error while executing a .exe file created using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cosine-similarity, sentence-transformers

I am trying to create a application which checks for sentence similarity.
.exe file got created.
I get the below error message while executing .exe file after giving required inputs.

Error Message

```
The 'tqdm>=4.27' distribution was not found and is required by this application.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main
```

spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['render_ui.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('Config\\favicon.ico',"."), ('Config\\miniLM.sav',".")],
             hiddenimports=['sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._datasets_pair', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._middle_term_computer', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._base', 'sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._radius_neighbors',
                            'sentence_transformers.SentenceTransformer'],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='App',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None,
          icon='Config\\favicon.ico')
```

I already have "tqdm==4.64.1" installed. I am not sure what is causing this problem.
Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: please create a [mre] and post any error messages you are receiving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after adding below instructions in spec file I was able to resolve the issue

```
datas += copy_metadata('tqdm')
datas += copy_metadata('regex')
datas += copy_metadata('requests')
datas += copy_metadata('packaging')
datas += copy_metadata('filelock')
datas += copy_metadata('numpy')
datas += copy_metadata('tokenizers')
datas += copy_metadata('importlib_metadata')
datas += copy_metadata('tensorflow')
```

Comment: Can you explain how you did this exactly. The .spec file is created after you run the build, even if you modify it will be updated after re-running the build

Comment: I manually added the above instructions into .spec file and then run the build

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are having issues with a dependency. The error message indicates that a package named `transformers`, likely a dependency of the executable you ran, is outdated.

Try running this line in your terminal:

```
pip install transformers -U
```

If that does not work, you can try debugging the environment by going to the directory where the executable is stored and using the command

```
pip freeze
```

If the version listed there is incorrect, you might need to uninstall and reinstall `tqdm`. To do this, execute the command

```
pip uninstall tqdm
```

and input `Y` when prompted. Then do

```
pip install tqdm
```

This forces pip to grab the latest version.

Comment: Similar solution using command line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865136/14819077