# pyinstaller exe file throws "No package metadata was found for The 'tqdm>=4.27'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pyinstaller, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to get an `.exe` file out of a script that is running a fastApi server. When openning the .exe file the cmd throws the following error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 563, in from_name
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 102, in require_version
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 1008, in version
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 981, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 565, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for tqdm

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "transformers\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 57, in <module>
  File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 117, in require_version_core
  File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 104, in require_version
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for The 'tqdm>=4.27' distribution was not found and is required by this application. 
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main
```

I am using a virtual venv to install the packages needed for the script. The packages include pytorch and transformers which are throwing this error. The main script is:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import uvicorn
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


app = FastAPI(debug=True)
# uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

# Allow requests from your React frontend origin
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Add your frontend's origin here
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


def pick_model(source_language, target_language):
    # Define a dictionary to map language combinations to model paths
    model_paths = {
        ("de", "fr"): r"path1",
        ("de", "en"): r"path2",
        ("en", "fr"): r"path3",
        ("de", "es"): r"path4",
        ("en", "de"): r"path5",
        ("en", "es"): r"path6",
        ("fr", "de"): r"path7",
    }

    # Build the model_path key using the source and target languages
    model_path_key = (source_language, target_language)

    # Check if the key exists in the dictionary, and return the corresponding model path
    if model_path_key in model_paths:
        return model_paths[model_path_key]
    else:
        return None  


# Manual cowboy inference
def translate_manual(input_text, model_path):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)
    inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_path)
    outputs = model.generate(
        inputs, max_new_tokens=40, do_sample=True, top_k=30, top_p=0.95
    )
    output_text = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return output_text


# Inference with pipeline()
def translate_pipeline(input_text, model_path):
    translator = pipeline("translation_XX_to_YY", model=model_path)
    output_text = translator(input_text, max_length=400)
    return output_text[0]["translation_text"]


class TextRequestModel(BaseModel):
    text: str
    sourceLanguage: str  # Include sourceLanguage in the model
    targetLanguage: str  # Include targetLanguage in the model


class CustomHTTPException(HTTPException):
    def __init__(self, detail: str, status_code: int = 500):
        super().__init__(status_code=status_code, detail=detail)


# root API endpoint
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    try:
        return {"message": "Hello, This is the root of IAV Translate App!"}
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomHTTPException(detail=str(e))


# Define API endpoints
@app.post("/translate/manual")
async def translate_manual_endpoint(request_data: TextRequestModel):
    try:
        text = request_data.text
        source_language = request_data.sourceLanguage
        target_language = request_data.targetLanguage
        # print("source_language", request_data.sourceLanguage)
        model_path = pick_model(source_language, target_language)
        # print("model_path", model_path)
        result = translate_manual(text, model_path)
        return {"translation": result}
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomHTTPException(detail=str(e))


@app.post("/translate/pipeline")
async def translate_pipeline_endpoint(request_data: TextRequestModel):
    try:
        text = request_data.text
        print(text)
        source_language = request_data.sourceLanguage
        target_language = request_data.targetLanguage
        model_path = pick_model(source_language, target_language)
        print(model_path)
        result = translate_pipeline(text, model_path)
        return {"translation": result}
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomHTTPException(detail=str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

To create the build of this script, I used the `pyinstaller`: `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py`. The resulted `main.spec` file is as follows ( I didn't change anything here, it was generated by default):

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Since I used a virtual environment, the pyinstaller should recognize all packages  and build the executable with regards to all installed packages but that wasn't the case. I have seen this solution [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75393856/tqdm-4-27-distribution-was-not-found-error-while-executing-a-exe-file-create), but it wasn't specified how to implement it as the `.spec` file is generated after the build is finished. So,how can I force the pyinstaller to recognize the missing packages? Thanks!!