# Cant create .exe with PyInstaller when OpenAI's Whisper is imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, openai-whisper

I am trying to create a small program that works with OpenAI's Whisper. I then build the Python script to the .exe file using PyInstaller (auto-py-to-exe). When I run the .exe file, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 108, in require_version
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 996, in version
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 969, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata\__init__.py", line 548, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for tqdm

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Whisper.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "whisper\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "whisper\decoding.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "whisper\tokenizer.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "transformers\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 123, in require_version_core
  File "transformers\utils\versions.py", line 110, in require_version
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for The 'tqdm>=4.27' distribution was not found and is required by this application.
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main
[10092] Failed to execute script 'Whisper' due to unhandled exception!
```

This is the source code of my program:

```
import whisper
import os
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start = timer()

audio_file = "MyAudioFile.wav"

model = whisper.load_model("small")

options = {"language": "de"}

res = model.transcribe(f"C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Transcribe/{audio_file}", **options)

end = timer()

os.system("cls")


print(res["text"])
print("\nFinished in " + str(end-start) + " seconds!")
input("Press ENTER to close the program.")
```

Everything works without problems when I run the Python script from the console or from VS code. However, unfortunately not when I start it as .exe.

I have already tried to reinstall the packages such as tqdm with pip, without success.

I am grateful for any help and hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding

```
--recursive-copy-metadata "openai-whisper"
```

to the PyInstaller command.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `.exe` is missing the `tqdm` dependency. In pyinstaller there is a `--hidden-import` option and according to [official blog](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/?utm_source=auto_py_to_exe&utm_medium=readme_link&utm_campaign=auto_py_to_exe_help#modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-x-importerror-no-module-named-x) for `auto-py-to-exe` you have to open the advanced tab and find the `--hidden-import` input and in your case include `tqdm`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it still does not work. I entered the following command (command by auto-py-to-exe):

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "tqdm" "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Transcribe/Test.py"

The error remains the same.

Comment: Interesting, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865136/11286032). It looks like they're using the `--copy-metadata` option and is a similar problem to the one you're having.